# Как в VBA при начале выполнения макроса указать окно для ввода нескольких значений?

Tags: vba

В общем при выполнении макроса мне нужно открыть диалоговое окно в котором будет сразу несколько полей и combobox с выбором. После указания всех значений мне нужно с ними работать. Как создать такое окно? В комбобоксе должно быть указано "Машина, Марка". Всего 2 значения в комбобоксе: Машина1 Марка1, Машина2 Марка2. Но дальше при работе мне нужно будет записать это в разные ячейки, к примеру в А1: Машина1, в А2: Марка1, А3: масса нетто, а4: масса брутто и т.д.

На данный момент у меня по очереди открываются окна в которых я ввожу по 1 значению, combobox вообще не знаю как сделать.

Вот как я открываю нужные мне окна, но они должны быть в одном окне:

```
inputNetto = Val(InputBox("Введите вес Нетто"))
NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 25).Value = inputNetto 

inputBrutto = Val(InputBox("Введите вес Брутто"))
NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(27, 23).Value = inputBrutto

inputPallets = Val(InputBox("Введите кол-во палетов"))
NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(27, 26).Value = inputPallets
```

Подскажите как реализовать такое окно, буду очень благодарен

Comment: ет такого диалогового окна. Нужно рисовать форму (*UserForm*)

Comment: Создать форму ввода значений. Без источника данных. /Процедурой открывать её, а уже в ней выполнять все нужные действия.

Comment: @Akina ok, это не критично. Времени нет разбираться как рисовать. Тогда можете показать как можно сделать combobox точно таким же окном ввода как я уже делал для других элементов и узнавать выбранные значения?

Comment: InputBox умеет принимать только скалярные строковые данные. Аналогичных стандартных компонентов, принимающих иные типы данных, в т.ч. с выбором из списка - увы, нету...

Comment: @Akina печально, ладно, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет такого диалогового окна. Нужно рисовать форму (*UserForm*).

Создаем форму - *Insert-UserForm*. Кнопочкой *ToolBox* вызываем окошко с элементами формы. Перетаскиваем нужные элементы на форму, размещае/форматируем. Параметры элемента (или формы) задаются в окне *Properties* (по *F4*).

Обработки элементов и самой формы (инициализирование, активация, изменение, выход и проч.) прописываются в модуле формы (ПКМ на форме - *View Code*)/

Двойной клик на элементе создает пустой макрос (обычно - событие изменения), в теле которого можно дописать необходимый код:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

Для удобства работы с формой элементы желательно переименовать:

*tBoxName* - TextBox для ввода имени, *cButClose* - кнопка закрытия и проч.

Часто при открытии формы должны быть заполнены списки, в зависимости от ситуации вписаны данные... Для придания форме требуемого вида - событие инициализации формы:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```